# Are there safety concerns using a web method to write to a database?

Tags: c#, jquery

Title is a pretty good indicator of my problem.  Is there security concerns using Jquery to fire a web method to update a database?  Are there reasons I should be doing all my database logic server side after a post?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you [follow best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site/305381#305381) (validate the input, prevent SQL injection and so on; check the link, it's good reading), this should not be any more dangerous than any other web based interface that ends up doing work in the database.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO there is no such problem. After all you jQuery calls will get to the server side at one point and you are still going to validate the input data,right?

Answer (score 1):

You should still make the same authorization checks as you normally would. There's also the same chance of N hits to your web method as there would be if someone kept reposting a form.